# .innerHTML problems storing it into a variable

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Here is my code that is not working - thanks guys - first question!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x =document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="myElementId">24</div>
<div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (x < 25) {
document.write("worked")
}
else {
document.write("didn't work")
}
</script>
```

Also sorry for the update but do you guys have an idea of how to do this when the div is in an iframe thats not on the same domain? Thanks

Comment: Tip: When you ask a question, describe what happens and describe what you *expect* to happen. *"Does not work"* is not a problem description.

Comment: At the time you are running the variable assignment (line 4), the DOM hasn't finished loading, therefore `myElementId` hasn't yet been created making it inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
var x = document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;
```

is executed **before** the element with ID `myElementId` exists, so JavaScript cannot find it (`getElementById` returns `null`).

Put it *after* the element:

```
<div id="myElementId">24</div>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;
</script>
```

The HTML document is processed from top to bottom.

Comment: do you have any idea of how do this if its a class instead of an id?

Answer (score 1):

You're running this line:

```
var x =document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;
```

before the element exists. Remove the script from the head an put that line right before:

```
if(x < 25) {
```

Instead.

Comment: great thank you! that worked but now I have another question - the value between the div tag (24) gets changed dynamically - but when it does change the if else doesn't get executed again. Is there away to fix that?

Comment: @Marco: Create a function that tests the value. Whenever you change the value, call the function. (And don't call `document.write` *after* the page was loaded, otherwise it will override the whole content).

Comment: You can bind a function to the onchange event of the div: `document.getElementById("myElementId").onchange = function(){ // do stuff };`

Comment: @Paul: I don't think the `change` event is triggered for normal DOM elements (only form elements). Or am I wrong?

Comment: @PaulPRO awesome! thank you - now do you have any idea of how do this if its a class instead of an id?

Comment: @Marco You can use `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead of `ById`, but it won't work in IE 8 or below. So you need to write your own function which uses it if it exists, and implements a slower way if it doesn't. Google `Cross browser getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: @Felix You're probably right, I forgot it was a div element. I'm not actually sure if the change event is triggered on a div, but I'm guessing it's not.

Comment: @PaulPRO strange that `code`document.getElementsByClassName() `code` is not working in my modern firefox - any suggestions?

Comment: @Marco It works in Firefox, just keep in mind that it returns a live NodeList or HTMLCollection since there can be more than one element on a page. You need to loop through the object, or if you know there is only one you can access the first element in the object using array notation: `document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0]` will be the first element with `class="someclass"`, `[1] will be the second element etc.`

Comment: @PaulPRO thanks that worked prefect! But I have another problem :( the div is inside an iframe. I didn't expect that to break this, any suggestions

Comment: @Marco is the iframe on the same domain as the outer page. It has to be for Javascript to work. Then you can access it like `frames[0].document.getElementsByClassName()` If the frame is on a different domain then it is impossible, for security reasons.

Comment: dang - yea the iframe is not on the same domain. Its actually a facebook like button plugin and the information I'm trying to pull out is the amount of likes which is wrapped around a div with a class. Any ideas?

Comment: @Marco what server side language do you use? Any PHP? Can you send me a link to the page with the like button?

Comment: @PaulPRO I can use PHP - have an idea?

Comment: ` <body>

<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=199283270134100&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.tennis-warehouse.com/Wilson_BLX_SixOne_95_16x18/descpageRCWILSON-6195BX.html" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" action="like" font=""></fb:like>


<script type="text/javascript">


var x =document.getElementsByClassName("connect_widget_button_count_count")[0].innerHTML;

if (x < 153) {
document.write("worked")
}
else {
document.write("didn't work")
}
</script>
</div>

</body> `

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the creating the element first,

I believe innerHtml returns a string value
   Try parsing it first;

```
var value  = document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;
var x   = parseInt(value,10)
```

Comment: @Richard - JavaScript will coerce the String to a Number, so `"10" < 20` is equal to `true`

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

```
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>
<div id="myElementId">24</div>
<div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x =document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;
if (x < 25) {
document.write("worked")
}
else {
document.write("didn't work")
}
</script>
```

the element that you are trying to look for does not even exist on the page when you run the script that is why you have run into this issue..

Comment: Yes, it does not work. I cannot see `worked` in the output and the console shows *`x` is not defined*. I know that `var x = document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;
` will work. But the other code will not.

Answer (score -2):

document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML;

You have to use a # with Id and . with class in it

document.getElementById("#myElementId").innerHTML;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `getElementById` doesn't work with query selectors as **#** , you are probably confusing it with `querySelector`